# Cordova 3.7 duplicates iframes on every native call

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, memory-leaks

Since I've upgraded to Cordova 3.7 every native call attaches a new iframe to the DOM like the one below.

```
<iframe src="gap://ready" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

To exclude the possibility of my existing code influencing cordova I've tried creating a new one with cordova CLI, adding console plugin and calling console.log() in a setInterval loop inside deviceready handler. As a result I got a ton of iframes in DOM.

I've tried this on iPad 3, iOS7, building the app using xCode 6.

Did anyone experience this issue? Thanks.

UPDATE:

Corresponding issue was filed to Cordova: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8002
The issue should be fixed in 3.8 release.

Comment: I would suggest posting this on cordova issues or forums.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm trying to figure out how stop making more and more iframes which at final takes a lot of ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved with the release of Cordova 3.8.0

Comment: I have the same problem currently with cordova 6.4.0

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced the same issue. I am not sure why this is happens. But changing the

```
if (bridgeMode === undefined) {
bridgeMode = jsToNativeModes.IFRAME_NAV;
}
```

block into

```
if (bridgeMode === undefined) {
bridgeMode = jsToNativeModes.XHR_NO_PAYLOAD;
}
```

in the cordova.js function iOSExec() works for me