# Why is my Cordova application creating so many iframes?

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, sencha-touch

I was debugging my Sencha/Cordova application on my device and was using [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/) for for debugging. When I looked at my index.html I noticed that it was creating about a hundred iframes:

[image: Pic]

It seems that if I navigate around my app it creates them. Is this something that I should be worried about?! If so what would be causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in Cordova iOS. Should be fixed in 3.8.0. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8002.

Also see this similar question: [Cordova 3.7 duplicates iframes on every native call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982981/cordova-3-7-duplicates-iframes-on-every-native-call)